# If a timer object is cleared from current workspace, will its callback function still trigger?

Tags: matlab, timer

If a timer object is cleared from the current workspace using [`clear`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html), will its `TimerFcn` still trigger at the scheduled time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **`clear`** doesn't remove the *object*, only the *variable* that refers to it. So it has **no effect**:

  ```
  close all
  t = timer('TimerFcn', 'figure', 'StartDelay', 3); % create figure after 3 seconds
  start(t)
  pause(2)
  clear t
  ```

  You will see the figure appearing after 3 seconds.
- To *remove the object* you use **`delete`**. This causes Matlab to stop the timer, and as a result **the timer function will not be executed**:

  ```
  close all
  t = timer('TimerFcn', 'figure', 'StartDelay', 3); % create figure after 3 seconds
  start(t)
  pause(2)
  delete(t)
  ```

  No figure appears. In fact, you get the very explicit

  ```
  Warning: You are deleting one or more running timer objects.  MATLAB has
  automatically stopped them before deletion.
  ```